# How do I return results from a second query if the first query didnt reach its limit?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this featured listings thing that will grab its information using

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE featured = '1' DESC LIMIT 5")`

However, if I didnt have enough results to display, how do I make it so that it would run `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY date desc")` till it reached the 5 limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query is missing an `order by`.  But the idea for solving your problem is to sort the data by *both* conditions, and then choose the first five:

```
SELECT *
FROM listings
ORDER BY (featured = '1') DESC,
         date
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt have any formal education to any of this, could you possibly link me to a documentation explaining how this works?

Comment: @Pa3k.m . . . These are all basic MySQL constructs.  The `order by` has two keys.  The first is a boolean, which is 1 when true and 0 when false.  The second is the date column.

Comment: Ok, let me get this clear, the query would select those with featured = '1' first then everything else?

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please ORDER BY (featured = '1') explain this